# Moving and re-ordering records permanently

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Items` e.g.

```
ID  Name     ItemOrder
----------------------
16  Albania  1
13  Chile    2
11  Barbados 3 
10  France   4
...
```

Which I display in my client application as

```
SELECT * FROM Items ORDER BY ItemOrder
```

I want to be able to "move" for example `Albania` and `Barbados` After (or Before depending on my parameter) `France` or any other record. so the result is (for move `After` record `France`):

```
13  Chile    1    
10  France   2 
16  Albania  3 
11  Barbados 4
```

And result for `Before` is:

```
13  Chile    1        
16  Albania  2 
11  Barbados 3 
10  France   4
```

I need to **update** permanently the `ItemOrder` to reflect the new order.
Is there  a simple and efficient way to do this?

Comment: How do we know which record to 'move' where(its not really moving, its ordering) ?

Comment: @sagi, Yes I need to update the ItemOrder to reflect the new order

Comment: are there only 4 records in table

Comment: @zig right, but your order is variable based on something else. what is that something else so it can be used to calculate your new item order?

Comment: @TheGameiswar, No. The records in that table can vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) to perform the `UPDATE` operation. This is how your query could look like for the 'After' case:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
  SELECT ID, Name, ItemOrder,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY temp_order) AS NewOrder
  FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name, ItemOrder,
         CASE 
            WHEN Name IN ('Albania', 'Barbados') THEN x.o + ItemOrder * 0.1 
          ELSE ItemOrder
         END AS temp_order
  FROM mytable 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT ItemOrder FROM mytable WHERE Name = 'France') AS x(o)) AS t
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET ItemOrder = NewOrder
```

The trick is to get `France's` order number and add a *fraction* of the order of 'Albania', 'Barbados', so that:

- 'Albania', 'Barbados' are positioned after 'France'
- 'Albania' and 'Barbados' maintain the order between them
- The order of the records following 'France' is also maintained.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af5de/3)

**Edit:**

The 'Before' case can be implemented if we substitute this line:

```
WHEN Name IN ('Albania', 'Barbados') THEN x.o + ItemOrder * 0.1
```

with this line:

```
WHEN Name IN ('Albania', 'Barbados') THEN x.o - 1.0/ItemOrder * 0.1
```

Comment: What does the `x.o` and `x(o)` mean?

Comment: @zig It's just an alias used to access the result returned by the `CROSS JOIN` operation.

Comment: This seems to work well. Still testing (I fail to understand this code fully yet) I tried to make a `Before` by changing `x.o + ItemOrder * 0.1` to `x.o - ItemOrder * 0.1` but the result is reversed although the records are Before France but the order does not maintain between them 'Albania', 'Barbados'. Can you please show me how to make a `Before` case?

Comment: I tested `CROSS JOIN (SELECT ItemOrder - 1 FROM @mytable WHERE Name = 'France') AS x(o)` (note the `-1`) and seems to work for  'Before' case. DO you think it's correct or should I use your `x.o - 1.0/ItemOrder * 0.1`?

Comment: No, it's not correct. You have to subtract by a number that is *less* than 1, so that you are certain that the records will be moved exactly before 'France'.

Comment: I see. I think I should multiply by a bigger fraction e.g. 0.0001 if ItemOrder is bigger than 100 or 1000 etc. right?

Comment: Also, why do we need the `* 0.1` in the Before case? shouldn't `x.o - 1.0/ItemOrder` be sufficient?

Comment: @zig Good catch! It was a left-over from the copy/paste!

Comment: @zig Hmmm, after a second thought, what happens in the special case that `ItemOrder = 1`. Then you might get unexpected results because two records will coincide.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that a min after I posted my comment. but the 0.1 needs to be calculated based on the **MAX** ItemOrder for a general solution I guess. My table could contain unknown number of records. I still can't get a 100% solution.

Comment: for the `After` case, I changed to `x.o + ItemOrder * (1.0 / 1000000)`. Seems to be ok. thanks for the help!

Comment: @zig sqlfiddle from time to time has serious lag issues

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This answer was written before you updated your question to mention that you need to *update* the ItemOrder.)

First, make some *space* between your entries:

```
SELECT ID, name, ItemOrder * 10 AS newOrder FROM Items
```

Now we modify that SQL to put the "special ones" in between:

```
SELECT ID, name, ItemOrder
       CASE WHEN name = 'Albania'
            THEN (SELECT ItemOrder FROM Items WHERE name = 'France') * 10 + 1
            WHEN name = 'Barbados'
            THEN (SELECT ItemOrder FROM Items WHERE name = 'France') * 10 + 2
            ELSE ItemOrder * 10
        END AS newOrder
  FROM Items
```

And now we can sort by it:

```
SELECT ID, name, ItemOrder
  FROM (... see previous SQL ...) AS t
 ORDER BY newOrder
```